# como fazer o log off automático depois que a sessão expirou?

Tags: php, session

estou com problemas, se o usuário ficar inativo por mais de 24 minutos, a página permanece a mesma.
Se estou na minha página e a sessão é expirada por inatividade (passou os 24 minutos), ainda consigo interagir na página, mas caso eu queira enviar os dados (mando esses dados via `ajax`) que já estavam semi populados no `HTML`, a página pede pra fazer `log in` denovo e todos esses dados são perdidos.

Existe algum modo deslogar depois que a sessão foi expirada se o usuário não interagiu nada com o formulário? ou algum outro approach que eu possa fazer?

```
public function run(){
    Session::init();

    $uname = $_POST['form-username'];
    $upass = $_POST['form-password'];
    $database = $this->db;
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM tabela
    WHERE  BINARY  user_name=:user_name AND BINARY user_pass=:user_pass LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $database->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(
        array(
            ':user_pass'=>$upass,
            ':user_name'=>$uname
        )
    );

    $resultado = $stmt->fetch();
    $contador = $stmt->rowCount() ;

    Session::set("loggedIn",false);
    if($contador > 0){
        Session::set("loggedIn",true);
        Session::set("id",$resultado['id']);
        header("location: ../outrapagina");
    } else {
        Session::set("mensagemErro","Login ou Senha Errada");
        header("location: ../login");
    }

}
```

Comment: Como você está fazendo para ver se já passou os 24 minutos? Poste seu código para que possa encontrar a ajuda que necessita.

Comment: na verdade não fiz nenhuma tratativa para verificar se passou dos 24 minutos, rs.

Comment: Está pelo menos autenticando? Como está fazendo para autenticar?

Comment: [Aqui você encontra uma resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/4843158) para expirar em 30 minutos, acho que irá te ajudar

Comment: No demais, sua pergunta está muito ampla assim. Aconselho [edit] para melhorar suas chances de ter a resposta que procura

Comment: fiz uma atualização

Comment: Você pode enviar requisições ajax constantemente para chegar se esta autenticado, ou manter uma conexão aberta como servidor, no qual ele checa constantemente se há ou não uma sessão ativa, e quando não houver, avisa o cliente.

Comment: Mas acredito que isso va consumir muito recurso. Talvez seja melhor você checar isso quando o usuário vai interagir com a página, ou formulário. Tipo, se ele começa a preencher um campo, você verifica e se se necessário, desloga.

Comment: Você pode enviar também um "keep alive" para impedir que a sessão expire enquanto a página estiver ativa no browser. Isso pode ser de 20 em 20 min.

Answer (score 3):

Um método relativamente simples é realizares uma chamada Ajax de x em x minutos, de forma a verificar se a sessão no lado do servidor já expirou.
Caso tenha expirado, direcionas o visitante para o URL pretendido.

#### sessao_ativa.php

```php
<?php
// iniciar sessão
session_start();

// se não existir a tua entrada de controlo ou a mesma for FALSE
if ( !isset($_SESSION["loggedIn"]) || !$_SESSION["loggedIn"] ) {
     echo "expirou";
}

// mata o script
die();
```

Na tua página a chamada Ajax:

```js
$.get('sessao_ativa.php', function(data) {
     if( data == "expirou" ) {
         window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';
     }
 });
```

Para executares a chamada Ajax, por exemplo, a cada 60 segundos:

```
// executa código a cada 60 segundos e guarda ID do temporizador
var temporizador = setInterval(function() {
    // chamada ajax aqui
}, 60 * 1000);

// se precisares cancelar por algum motivo
clearInterval(temporizador);
```

Comment: Zull como vai? Não fui eu quem negativou, mas gostaria de lhe sugerir que use o evento `.done` (ou `"success":`) do jQuery combinado com `setTimeout`, o uso de `setInterval` da maneira que utilizou pode fazer múltiplas requisições sem um esperar a outra.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Só deixei um exemplo que deverá ser adaptado à realidade do código do OP. De qualquer forma, o `setInterval` funciona bem para estes cenários... pelo menos nas implementações que tenho feito :) Mas só deve estar um a correr, dois ou mais e ai sim, começa tudo a ficar descontrolado e o browser a arrastar-se!

Comment: Trabalhei em um sistema de chat, o qual inicialmente usei o `setInteval` + `ajax`, com o fluxo de muitos usuários ao mesmo tempo ocorreram picos desnecessários em meu servidor, fora os conflitos de eventos concorrentes que podem ocorrer, no caso por se um redirecionamento provavelmente não ocorra, mas qualquer nova implementação pode ser prejudicada. Até mais!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, o que falas pode ocorrer, mas repara que o PHP desta chamada ajax executa 1 tarefa que demora micro-segundos a realizar. Já o `setInterval` só corre a cada 60 segundos ;)

Comment: Entendo sim :), mas imagine que ocorre um delay no teu servidor devido a algum script com execução longa, isto irá afetar o front-end, quanto mais usuários acessando então em certo momento haverá dois ou mais eventos correndo ao mesmo tempo, isto eu digo apenas para um usuário, mas pode ocorrer em vários em um periodo que os usuários fiquem em média 10 minutos dentro do site, então haverá mais requisições que o normal, podendo eventualmente ocorrerem picos, principalmente se estiver usando algum REST ou banco com mysql, postgresql, etc. Isto é apenas uma sugestão ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ficávamos aqui a noite toda a imaginar cenários ;) Mas como referi, concordo contigo, apesar que só deixei um exemplo prático. A pergunta em si não se foca num problema especifico a resolver, ela dá aso a um universo de soluções... eu parti pela mais simples que me ocorreu!

Comment: Entendo e realmente tenho que concordar, só fiquei com receio mesmo de pegarem tal código pra usarem em diversos situações, aonde pode ocorrer os cenários que pensei, mas realmente é pouco provavel, obrigado pelo empenho, deixarei +1 que pois acredito ser uma solução também.